# Correct Ternary Condition for IF ElseIf Condition

Tags: php

Here is my If Else Statement

```
if(isset($row['content']) && strlen($row['content'])) {
  $content = $row['content'];
}
elseif(isset($row['description']) && strlen($row['description'])) {
  $content = $row['description'];
}
```

I tried to create a condition using ternerary operator and ended for with a error: Here is my ternerary condition

```
$content = isset($row['content']) && strlen($row['content']) ? $row['content'] : isset($row['description']) && strlen($row['description']) ? $row['description'] : '';
```

What is the correct statement?

Comment: 'ended for with a error' ... what error exactly? Also, a ternary operator does not add any additional benefits (unless it's very small and concise, although arguable), the if/else statement are a lot more readable in this case.

Comment: Error Type is "Notice" and is "Undefined index: description"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting inside bracket the first term of `?:` and the last term of first `?:`.

```
$content = (isset($row['content']) && strlen($row['content'])) ? $row['content'] : ((isset($row['description']) && strlen($row['description'])) ? $row['description'] : '');
```

Comment: Just what I needed for resolving a notice

Answer (score 3):

You're making your code very very unreadable by changing your condition into a ternary operator. Anyhoo, the following works without an error.

```
$content =  (isset($row['content']) && strlen($row['content'])) 
        ? $row['content'] 
        : (isset($row['description']) && strlen($row['description']) 
            ? $row['description'] 
            : '');
```

Wrapped the last expression in parenthesis so PHP doesn't try to evaluate it separately.

Comment: JohnP, Can you also look into my last question and help me solve that json error